# How to "convert" nested loops into code taking advantage of parallel computing?

Tags: parallel-computing

Let's say that an algorithm uses several nested loops to accomplish it's task, for instance :

- An algorithm treating voxels on several frames, so there would be
  four dimensions : t (for time), x, y and z.
- An algorithm evaluating a
  function that takes n entries, searching for which entries there is a
  certain result. For instance if we search f(a, b, c, d, e) = 2001
  where each variable is tested between 0 and 100.

From what I understand, several APIs make you model the way your kernel is executed by the GPU with a 1-2-3d grid, but many of them don't provide n-dimensional grids for execution.

So if I had to treat a simple 2D image of 1024x2048 pixels, I could have simply made my kernel execute itself over a grid of that size instead of having to nest loops, but since most grids seem to be limited to 3 dimensions, what to do when I need to execute work for more than 3 dimensions (like in my second example) ?
Should I put loops directly in my kernels ?

Thank you.

**EDIT :**
Some pseudocode :
Let's say that I want to test for which inputs a given function has a certain value, I could have some *brute force* approach like that :

```
for a in 1...100 {
for b in 1...100 {
for c in 1...100 {
for d in 1...100 {
     if f(a,b,c,d) == 1984 {
        equationSolutions.append((a,b,c,d))
     }
}
```

Now with grids, a certain kernel can be executed *over* the grid (sorry, I may not use the right term, there is a much better explaination about grids [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlcomputecommandencoder)), so if you want to treat each pixel of an image of 2048x512 pixels, instead of doing :

```
for x in 0...imageWidth {
for y in 0...imageHeight {
   treatPixel(x,y)
}
```

You will define grid as a 2D grid of size 2048x512 and then your kernel won't contain any loop, it will just get it's position on the grid as an argument :
func myPixelFunction(positionInGrid) {
treatPixel(positionInGrid.x, positionInGrid.y)
}

My question is that, since most grids are limited to 3 dimensions, what to do if you want to execute code that requires *more* than 3 dimensions ? (like my code trying to solve a function ?).

From what I understand, in cases like the ones I showed, grids make more sense than loops on GPUs since grids enable to parallelise the work, making several threads work in parallel on the same function/kernel, but while it's really easy to simply use position in grid when you are treating data that is representable by the grid, I don't understand how to write code using grids when I needs to word on "additional dimensions".

**EDIT #2 :**
[This SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048811/how-do-i-setup-my-cuda-thread-blocks-and-grids-for-eight-dimensions) is similar to mine.

Comment: Can you help me understand your question?  What does "kernel" mean?  Do you just mean the algorithm/function f?  What do you mean by a 1-2-3d grid or by "provide n-dimensional grids for execution"?  What do you mean by "tread"?  What does it mean to execute  a kernel over a grid, and how is that different from a nested loop?  Are you talking about the difference between executing these iterations in parallel vs sequentially?  What kind of answer do you expect?  Are you looking for an algorithm, or for code?

Comment: @D.W. Kernel is for function executed by GPU. Grid is the way some GPU APIs (such as Metal or CUDA) define how your kernel is gonna be executed (nice explanation here https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlcomputecommandencoder). Wrong typo, I meant "thread" not "tread". For what it means to execute kernel over a grid see the link. About the nested loops vs grid, I'll update my answer to try to make it clearer.

Comment: @D.W. Oops, sorry again, that wasn't "thread" that was "treat".

Comment: @D.W. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to iterate over `a,b,c,d` each ranging from `0..99`.  There are two ways to do that.

### Approach #1: fewer nested loops

Set up a 100x100 grid, which will handle `a,b`.  Handle `c,d` by explicit nested loops:

```
treatPixel(a,b):
for c in 0..99:
    for d in 0..99:
        doSomething(a,b,c,d)
```

### Approach #2: bigger grid

Set up a 10,000x10,000 grid.  Then decode the x-coordinate to `a,b` and the y-coordinate to `c,d`, like this:

```
treatPixel(x,y):
a := floor(x/100); b := x mod 100
c := floor(y/100); d := y mod 100
doSomething(a,b,c,d)
```

### Which to choose?

Either one should work.

Assuming the number of iterations greatly exceeds the number of compute elements in the GPU, the difference between the two probably comes down to different memory locality effects.  You can try implementing both of them, benchmarking, and seeing if one is faster.  If there is little or no memory access and `doSomething()` is compute-bound, they'll probably both run at about the same speed.

Comment: Thank you ! Somebody once told me that mod is pretty expensive, do you think I should be concerned about that in my case ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise, I don't know.  It probably depends on how much work `doSomething()` does.   Note also that you can replace `b := x mod 100` with `b := x - 100*a`, if that helps (a multiply might be faster than a remainder/mod, depending on the architecture).  The best way to know for sure is probably to benchmark it.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise If the iteration count is a power of two, the modulo operation can be replaced by a bitwise `&` (assuming your architecture is base 2)